# Spring boot After logout session scoped bean is not changing

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am using spring boot and thymeleaf. When a user logout and another user login,  if i access

```
    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
```

directly, it shows new user. but if I autowire the bean defined as

```
@Bean(name = "loggedInUser")
@SessionScope
public UserMaster userMaster() {
    UserMaster user;
    try {
        user = (UserMaster) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
        user.setAuthorities(userService.getUserAuthorities(user.getUserId()));

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        System.out.println("user Not logged in");
        user = new UserMaster();
    }
    return user;
}
```

it shows old user.

my security configuration for logout is

```
            .logout().logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
            .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID").clearAuthentication(true)
            .invalidateHttpSession(true).permitAll()
```

if bean is session scoped and we are invalidating session on logout then why it shows old data.

Please help me what i am doing wrong here.

Thanks

Comment: Are you certain that "/logout" is called and logout logic is applied? You could add a `.logoutSuccessHandler()` to verify that logout succeeded. Btw, why not simply `.logout().logoutUrl("/logout")` instead of the `AntPathRequestMatcher`?

Comment: Yes logout logic is applied. It redirects to login page on logout. I tested again as you suggested using logoutSuccessHandler.

Comment: Have you verified that the bean works as expected and is indeed session scoped, holding the correct authentication object when, for example, logging in two different users in different browsers?

Comment: yes it do work. in fact it works fine if users have different roles but not if user have same role (just realized this).

Comment: From the code snippets you posted the problem is apparent. The problem is probably caused elsewhere is your setup.

Comment: you are right thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This configuration had nothing wrong. problem was, where I autowired the bean I modified it before sending to view. However I still don't understand why it kept the old value (my guess is cache),
using a different object for view fixed the problem.